# Getting a sum via Green's function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, greens-function

Consider the following question:

> Consider the real Sturm-Liouville problem
> $$
> \mathcal{L} y(x)=-\left(p(x) y^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+q(x) y=\lambda r(x) y
> $$
> with the boundary conditions $y(a)=y(b)=0$, where $p, q$ and $r$ are continuous and positive on $[a, b]$. Show that, with suitable choices of inner product and normalisation, the eigenfunctions $y_n(x), \quad n=1,2,3 \ldots$, form an orthonormal set.
> Hence show that the corresponding Green's function $G(x, \xi)$ satisfying
> $$
> (\mathcal{L}-\mu r(x)) G(x, \xi)=\delta(x-\xi)
> $$
> where $\mu$ is not an eigenvalue, is
> $$
> G(x, \xi)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{y_n(x) y_n(\xi)}{\lambda_n-\mu},
> $$
> where $\lambda_n$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $y_n$.
> Find the Green's function in the case where
> $$
> \mathcal{L} y \equiv y^{\prime \prime},
> $$
> with boundary conditions $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$, and deduce, by suitable choice of $\mu$, that
> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}
> $$

I showed that the desired Green's function is
$$G(x,\xi)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\pi(-\mu -n)} \cos (n x) \cos (\xi n).$$
However, I am unsure as how to proceed. I tried setting up a problem with
$$
(\mathcal{L} -\mu)y= f(x)
$$
for $f$ being $x,\sin ,\cos$ and then trying to match the analytic solution with the one from Green's function, however, nothing worked. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Would you mind uploading a picture of the original exercise? Something just seems off about this

Comment: :@K.defaoite of course. This is from an exam paper https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/files/2002/PaperIB_3.pdf . This is question 12 on page 6.

Comment: I think the eigenfunctions are $\sin$ , not $\cos$ ...

Comment: Also the eigenvalues are going to be $n^2$, not $n$

Comment: Hi, I think that you are right. However, I still don't see how to proceed. Any ideas? I will edit the question shortly.

Comment: Unfortunately I am in the same boat, not sure how to proceed. I'll give it some more thought while I'm on the bus.

Comment: Ah ok. I see what's going on. You can set $x=\xi=\pi/2$ and set $\mu=0$ to get $G(\pi/2;\pi/2\mid 0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. Using your expression for $G$ you can deduce $G(\pi/2;\pi/2\mid 0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/6$ from which you can deduce (by splitting into even+odd integers) that $\sum_{n~\text{odd}}\frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/8$.

Comment: The problem is quite misleading, because as written it seems like you should be getting $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$ falling directly out of the problem, when in reality you solve the Basel problem first and then deduce the odd sum by simple algebra.

Comment: I agree, thank you for writing this. Feel free to post it as an answer and I will gladly accept it. Just to clarify, how does one know the value of the sum? I thought that we are supposed to use Green's function to construct a series solution and then match it with a closed form one, by which I mean some standard function that is not expanded.

Comment: Actually no, I was wrong. Notice that $\sin(n\pi / 2)$ is zero for even $n$. So in fact all you get is the odd terms. I will show this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll assume from the start that $r=1$*.

---

You know that the Green's function for the linear operator $\mathscr L-\mu$ where
$$(\mathscr L y)(x)=-\mathrm D(py')(x)+qy$$
Is
$$G(x;\xi\mid \mu)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{y_n(x)y_n(\xi)}{\lambda_n-\mu}$$
I.e, it is the unique solution of the equation
$$(\mathscr Ly)(x)-\mu y(x)=\delta(x-\xi)$$
With homgeneous Dirichlet BCs.

Here $\{(y_n,\lambda_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are the nontrivial orthonormal eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the operator $\mathscr L$, that is they satisfy
$$\mathscr Ly_n=\lambda_ny_n \\ \langle y_m,y_n\rangle=\int_a^by_m(x)y_n(x)\mathrm dx=\delta_{m,n}$$

In the case of $p=1$ and $q=0$, and BCs $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$ you know that the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues are (The scaling is important here!)
$$\lambda_n=n^2 \\ y_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(nx)$$
Hence, your Green's function is
$$G(x;\xi\mid \mu)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)\sin(n\xi)}{n^2-\mu}$$

So, we could write
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n\pi/2)\sin(n\pi/2)}{n^2}=\sum_{n~\text{odd}}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}G(\pi/2;\pi/2\mid 0)$$

However, we also know ([link1](https://web.math.utk.edu/%7Efreire/teaching/m431f14/DirichletBVP.pdf),[link2](https://youtu.be/8l4VsNSX_kw)) that, given functions $u,v$ that nontrivially satisfy the equation $\mathscr L y=0$ with $u(a)=0~,~v(b)=0$ that our Green's function (with $\mu=0$) may be expressed as

$$G(x;\xi)=\begin{cases}\frac{u(x)v(\xi)}{p(\xi)W(\xi)} & x<\xi \\ \frac{v(x)u(\xi)}{p(\xi)W(\xi)} & x>\xi\end{cases}$$

Where $W=uv'-vu'$.

Again in our case taking $p=1,q=0$ we can see that our fundamental solutions are
$$u(x)=x~~,~~v(x)=\pi-x$$

Hence
$$G(x;\xi\mid 0)=\frac{1}{\pi}\begin{cases}x(\pi-\xi) & x<\xi \\ \xi(x-\pi) & x>\xi\end{cases}$$

Therefore
$$\frac{\pi}{2}G(\pi/2;\pi/2\mid 0)  =\frac{\pi}{2}~\frac{1}{\pi}~\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\pi^2/8$$

Hence
$$\sum_{n~\text{odd}}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$
Done.

---

Additionally, this also allows you to work out

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n~\text{even}}\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{n~\text{odd}}\frac{1}{n^2} \\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^2}+\sum_{n~\text{odd}}\frac{1}{n^2} \\ \implies \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n~\text{odd}}\frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/8 \\ \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/6.$$

Comment: Notice that the sum over the integers reduces to a sum over ODD integers because $\sin(n\pi/2)$ is zero when $n$ is odd!

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: Just a quick question, when you found the eigen functions is there any specific reason you picked the positive square root?

Comment: @MathsWizzard It doesn't make any difference, but good point.\